# toggle button: How to have same contents between the editors when I toggle?

Tags: button, ckeditor, toggle

I am trying to implement a toggle switch-toggle between textarea and ckeditor in my web form.
As of now I am able to toggle between the 2 editors.But I am not able to have the same contents in both the editors. Its treating it like 2 separate textarea, I want them to have the same contents when I toggle from textarea to ckeditor.Can anybody help me and lemme know what I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Code:

### Updated code

```
 <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" class="ckeditor" rows="20" cols="75"></textarea>
     <input type="button" value="CKEditor" onclick="CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');" />
     <input type="button" value="Text editor" onclick="CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.destroy('editor1');" />        
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

  </form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.destroy()` to restore it to a textarea and call `CKEDITOR.replace('editor1')` again when you want a CKEditor.

Remove the whole `<div id="textarea">` because otherwise you will get unexpected results, you're using two textareas with the same id and name.

Comment: I implemented in the way you suggested, but still the data is not synchronized between ckeditor and text area.

Comment: If you do it correctly then it should work. Check that you have only one textarea and that you don't have any javascript errors.

Comment: Thanks for ur input. I now have just 1 textarea :editor1 now.As before the toggle is working.Data in the editors are not in sync i.e., if i am using ckeditor and then switch to textarea, the data present in ckeditor is not in textarea. Have updated the code in the question with ur input.

Comment: You are passing a parameter to .destroy(), but my example was without any parameter. The only parameter allowed is a boolean "noUpdate", so your string is converted to a boolean true and so the instance isn't updated when you destroy it. Check the API: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#destroy

Comment: Thanks a ton. It worked. Henceforth will look at the API definition first.:-)

Comment: Put destroy(true) works like a charm. Thanks for your reference @AlfonsoML